# Not able to decode the encoded unicode string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, decoding

i am not able to decode this encoded string to its unicode value:- `%5Cu20A8`

```
NSData *unicodedStringData =
    [@"%5Cu20A8" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSString *stringValue =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I have tried `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` as well but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked:-

```
NSString *unicodedString = [[dictMain objectForKey:@"currency"] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

NSData *unicodedStringData = [unicodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *currencyUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Just removing percent escapes before decoding the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just improved Ashish's answer

```
NSString *unicodedString = [@"%5Cu20A8" stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

NSData *unicodedStringData = [unicodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *currencyUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",currencyUnicode);
```

Output - ₨